# WP7: NullReference Exception when referring to element

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

i'm developing a Windows Phone 7.1 Application,
this is the ApplicationBar :

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
  <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True"
                        IsMenuEnabled="True">
    <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/add.png"
                                    Text="Add"
                                    x:Name="addItem"
                                    Click="addItem_Click" />
    <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/edit.png"
                                    Text="Edit"
                                    x:Name="edit"
                                    IsEnabled="False"
                                    Click="edit_Click" />
    <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/remove.png"
                                    Text="Remove"
                                    x:Name="remove"
                                    IsEnabled="False"
                                    Click="remove_Click" />
    <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
      <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="Clear"
                                    x:Name="clr"
                                    Click="clr_Click" />
      <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="Logout"
                                    Click="ApplicationBarMenuItem_Click"
                                    x:Name="logout" />
    </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
  </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
```

when i refer to its elements, named 'edit' and 'remove' :

```
edit.IsEnabled = true;
        remove.IsEnabled = true;
```

it gets nullreference exception.
 any solutions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have to retreive the object in code behind :

```
ApplicationBarIconButton edit = ApplicationBar.Buttons[1] as ApplicationBarIconButton;
edit.IsEnabled = true;
```

Comment: @Ashura - I tried your solution and it worked for me.  Thank you.  What a shame that you can't rely on simply giving the button a name in the XAML.  If you care to share how you figured this out I'd like to know.