# ApplicationBarIconButton name reference results in NullReferenceException but not in all Windows Phone 7 apps?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, nullreferenceexception

I had a problem today with application bar icon buttons.  Despite having valid *x:Name* values in the Main page XAML, trying to reference the buttons using the assigned *name* resulted in a NullReferenceException.  Hovering the IDE tooltip over the name reference dis show a NULL value upon inspection.

I found this post on SO that gave me a workaround:

[WP7: NullReference Exception when referring to element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475339/wp7-nullreference-exception-when-referring-to-element)

However, I remembered that in another project I have I did not have this problem.  In that project the *name* references do have valid values and I *am* able to access the application bar buttons via their assigned *x:Name* values set in the Main page XAML.  Both projects target **Windows O/S 7.1** as their platforms, and I can't see anything different between the relevant XAML's or the Main page load logic that would indicate the root of the problem.

Does anybody know why this happens in one Windows Phone 7 project and not the other?

**Main page XAML for app that does not have the null-reference problem**

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True" x:Name="PhoneAppBar" Opacity="0.0">
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Icons/appbar.feature.video.rest.png" Text="record"  x:Name="StartRecording" Click="StartRecording_Click" />
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Icons/appbar.stop.rest.png" Text="stop" x:Name="StopPlaybackRecording" Click="StopPlaybackRecording_Click"/>
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Icons/appbar.transport.play.rest.png" Text="play" x:Name="StartPlayback" Click="StartPlayback_Click"  />
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Icons/appbar.transport.pause.rest.png" Text="linked" x:Name="PausePlayback" Click="PausePlayback_Click" IsEnabled="False"/>
    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
```

**Main page XAML for the app that does have the problem**

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="False">
        <shell:ApplicationBar.Buttons>
            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton x:Name="btnRecord" Text="record" IconUri="/images/record.png" Click="Record_Click"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton x:Name="btnPlay" Text="play" IconUri="/images/play.png" Click="Play_Click" IsEnabled="False"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton x:Name="btnStop" Text="stop" IconUri="/images/stop.png" Click="Stop_Click"/>
        </shell:ApplicationBar.Buttons>
    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
```

Comment: The surprising isn't that it doesn't work on your new project, but that it works in your other project. Are you sure you didn't put some kind of workaround in the code-behind?

Comment: @KooKiz Not to my knowledge.  The working bit is from an MSDN video recording sample and I gave a good going over to see if there's anything different.  But so far I can't find anything.

Comment: Could you share the code of that app somehow? I really wish to understand how it could work

Answer (score 2):

Actually it is a known problem for AppBar elements. You have to access the buttons via index from the AppBar itself.

```
var  button =  this.ApplicationBar.Buttons[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

The x:Name allows you to access the appbar item from the code behind on that page. Especially since appbar is a shell object and can't be directly bound to, you need to use x:Name to access it's properties.

Looking at your code, the one that gives you the problem does not have an x:Name for the appbar. If you are trying to reference it, you will get a null reference exception when looking for "PhoneAppBar"

Comment: I just tried giving the appbar a name but the name reference at run-time resolves to NULL, just like the buttons.  Still happens after a Clean and a rebuild.